# node.js child_process spawn ignoring equal signs

Tags: node.js, cordova, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to launch a cordova command with a target device. I've tested the command and it works but when I try to generate it with my code, it ignores the equal sign and therefore won't run. This code does work just not with the addition of `"--target='iPhone-7-Plus"`

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const executable = "ionic";
  const arguments = [
    "cordova",
    buildOnly ? "build" : "run",
    platform,
    "--no-interactive",
    "--verbose",
    "--target='iPhone-7-Plus'"
  ].concat(releaseDev === "release" ? ["--prod", "--release"] : []);
  console.log(executable, arguments.join(" "));
  const child = spawn(executable, arguments, {
    stdio: "inherit"
  });
  child.on("close", () => resolve());
  child.on("error", err => reject(err));
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why would it be ignoring my equal sign only but the rest of the command gets added?

If I run `cordova run ios --target='iPhone-7-Plus'` the command will execute and launch the 7+ simulator without issues.

Comment: I see `'` in that line `"--target='iphone-7-plus"`, might this be the problem?

Comment: @DavidGatti My bad, I copied that wrong. In my code it does have both `'` and runnning `cordova run ios --target='iPhone-7-Plus'` executes without issues when typed directly into the command line.

Comment: I recommend updating the questions then. And what about removing this if else statement form inside the array `buildOnly ? "build" : "run",` some hardcore approach to go about this, I'd also do a console.log of `arguments` before passing it to Spaw to see how it looks after all that manipulation that you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When spawning I had to add `shell: true` in order to use the default shell for my os. The shell that spawn was using would strip special characters.

```
const child = spawn(executable, arguments, {
  stdio: "inherit",
  shell: true
});
```